# When to use require and when to use import in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

Into my second day of Aurelia and I have seen how custom attributes can be created and used.

To use the custom attribute my view html used:

```
<require from="./highlightattribute"></require>
```

However I have found some other code which uses:

```
<import from='./chord-diagram'></import>
```

When do I use require and when do I use import?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<import from=...` is the old syntax. We had to move to `<require from...` to aid in supporting older versions of IE. So please always use `<require from...`.

Comment: Thanks Ashley once again. I tried changing import to require but that did not work which makes sense.